# Postgresql How to Grouping and Fill the field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with field has been hashed like this:

> **order_id, order_detail_id**
>
> //qwe221, jdeiwe
>
> //qwe221, eudasd
>
> kasdaw25, saderf
>
> kasdaw25, syehsd
>
> kasdaw25, kredss

I want to make it like this so it is easier to be maintain

> **order_id, order_detail_id, order_id_alias**
>
> //qwe221, jdeiwe, 1
>
> //qwe221, eudasd, 1
>
> kasdaw25, saderf, 2
>
> kasdaw25, syehsd, 2
>
> kasdaw25, kredss, 2

Please help me, explain how to do it step by step IN SQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use window function

```
select *, dense_rank() over(order by order_id) order_id_alias from t
```

Comment: It works! thanks! but now how to insert the result to the field order_id_alias in db?

Comment: it works like this :
with new_values as (
   select *, dense_rank() over(order by order_id) diff from t
)
update t
  set order_id_alias = new_values.diff
from new_values 
where new_values.order_id = t.order_id;

do dense_rank start number can be defined? like it should start from 1000?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert using,

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col_1, col_2, col_3)
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3
FROM another_table
WHERE col_1 = 'value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the table using:

```
update t
    set order_id_alias = tt.seqnum
    from (select order_id, row_number() over (order by order_id) as seqnum
          from t
          group by order_id
         ) tt
    where t.order_id = tt.order_id;
```

Note:  You may need to add the `order_id_alias` column into the table, if it is not already there.